# How to Create a Dynamic Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Using code below you can create a fully responsive dynamic owl carousel.
The same way you can implement this carousel in magento2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="myjs2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <style>
    body
{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size : 10pt;
    padding:15px;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
}
h1 
{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin: 20px;
}
.owl-item 
{
    background-color: black;
}
#close
{
    float: right;
    align-items: right;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
    z-index: 999;
}
</style>
    <title>yes</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test"></div>
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
</div>

<br> <br> <br> <br>
<button id="addCarous"> Add Carousel</button>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

     navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
     slideSpeed : 300,
     paginationSpeed : 400,
     items : 3, 
     itemsDesktop : false,
     itemsDesktopSmall : false,
     margin:10,
     nav:true,
     itemsTablet: false,
     itemsMobile : false
 });

});

$("#addCarous").click(function(e){

owl =  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
slideSpeed : 300,
paginationSpeed : 400,
items : 3, 
itemsDesktop : false,
itemsDesktopSmall : false,
margin:10,
nav:true,
itemsTablet: false,
itemsMobile : false
});
            
var number = document.getElementsByClassName("item").length +1;
    e.preventDefault(); //-- prevent form submit
    $('#owl-demo').trigger('add.owl.carousel', ['<div class="item" id='+number+'> <span class="close" id="close" onclick="remove_image(this);"> X </span> <br> <h1> slide '+number+'  <h1> <br> <img src="test.jpg">  </div>'])
        .trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
});


function remove_image(trigger) {
    var $item = $(trigger).closest('.owl-item');
    var index = $item.closest('.owl-stage').children().index($item);
    alert(index);
    $item.closest('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel('remove', index).owlCarousel('update');
    
 if(owl.hasClass('owl-theme')){

owl.trigger('destroy.owl.carousel');
owl.find('.owl-stage-outer').children().unwrap();
owl.removeClass("owl-center owl-loaded owl-text-select-on");
owl = $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons

slideSpeed : 300,
paginationSpeed : 400,

items : 3, 
itemsDesktop : false,
itemsDesktopSmall : false,
margin:10,
nav:true,
itemsTablet: false,
itemsMobile : false

});
owl.owlCarousel();

}

owl.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');


}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```